Why output in PL/SQL Cursor code outputs twice
Wondering why the below code will output 'hello' twice? (when there is only 1 output line)
thanks.
DECLARE
cursor c is
Select 'hello' from dual;

word varchar2(100);

BEGIN

open c;
   loop
   fetch c into word;
   dbms_output.put_line(word);
   exit when c%notfound;
   end loop;

END;


Put the "EXIT" immediately after the FETCH. The loop will have 2 iterations. The first one gets the records, the 2nd one doesn't find a record but still has the value from the first iteration and prints that, then exits. Your code does the following:
DECLARE
   l_loopcounter NUMBER := 1;
   CURSOR c IS
   SELECT 'hello'
     FROM dual;

   word VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   OPEN c;
   LOOP
      FETCH c INTO word;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_loopcounter || '-' || word);
      l_loopcounter := l_loopcounter + 1;
      EXIT WHEN c%notfound;
   END LOOP;

END;
/


1-hello
2-hello


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Move the EXIT statement to immediately after FETCH statement:
DECLARE
   l_loopcounter NUMBER := 1;
   CURSOR c IS
   SELECT 'hello'
     FROM dual;

   word VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   OPEN c;
   LOOP
      FETCH c INTO word;
      EXIT WHEN c%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_loopcounter || '-' || word);
      l_loopcounter := l_loopcounter + 1;
   END LOOP;

END;
/
1-hello


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

